# Kite Diagram in R

Tags: r, matrix, ggplot2, diagram

I am trying to re-create a kite diagram showing the distribution of the most abundant macroalgal species.

My data is below:

Here: `dput(p2[1:3, 1:5])`

```r
structure(c(25.04240506, 24.95759494, 24.04113924, 25.0164557, 
24.9835443, 24.04905063, 25.00379747, 24.99620253, 24.03955696, 
25.01677215, 24.98322785, 24.01740506, 25.00474684, 24.99525316, 
24.03955696), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("Sphacelaria tribuloides(O)", 
"Amphiroa rigida (R)", "Stypocaulon scoparium (O)"), c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "B1", "B2")))
```

Current output:

[![This is what my plot looks like][1]][1]

Goal:

[![This is what my kite diagram should look like][2]][2]

I am truly not sure what I am doing wrong and or how to go about fixing it.

Thank you very much for your help and guidance in advance. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how what you are getting differs from your expectations? The second picture you post looks pretty good, I think.

Comment: Additionally, to get help writing code, please (a) share a **small reproducible subset** of your data, preferably in copy/pasteable R syntax. It's much more useful for you to share, say, 3 rows and 5 columns in a copypasteable way, than all of your data in a difficult-to-use way. `dput` makes this easy, just give us `dput(your_data[1:3, 1:5])`. (b) Please show the code you ran. What package is the `kitechart` function you used from? How did you call it? Did you try any other options?

Comment: Thank you---the data improves your post immensely. Can you also please address the other points in my comments? Namely, what `kitechart` function are you using (from what package?) and how are you using it? And what don't you like about what you are getting? The second plot you show looks fine to me... you say "I am truly not sure what I am doing wrong". As for me, I don't even know *why you think anything is wrong at all*.

Comment: Hi, Greg, I just updated my post and used "dput" to share a small reproducible subset of my data. The second photo I posted is what it should look like and what I am trying to replicate. I can't seem to make it look like that at all and only get the rainbow plot (1st photo).  b) the code I ran was kiteChart(p2) which comes from the plotrix package. I also tried  p2<-melt(p), ggplot(data=p2, aes(fill=p3$X1)) +
facet_grid(p3$X2~.,space="free", scales="free_y") +
geom_ribbon(aes(x=p3$X2,ymin=-value,ymax=+value))
but nothing shows.

Comment: @ART: please add the code to your question. It's difficult to read code in comments

Comment: Ah, first picture: result; second picture: goal. That's the key info I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: I change values of your example, in order to get more variations as all your values were all between 24 or 25 which explain why you get almost horizontal bar in your kite Diagram. I did:

```r
df[1:3,1:5] <- sample(5:25, 15, replace = TRUE)

                           A1 A2 A3 B1 B2
Sphacelaria tribuloides(O)  9 18 20  5 17
Amphiroa rigida (R)         6 18 24 18 18
Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  16 18 16 19  8
```

To get a kite diagram, you can simply use `kiteChart` function from `plotrix` diagram.

```r
library(plotrix)
kiteChart(df)
```

[image]

I did not find a way to rotate y labels as it seems that `yaxt = "n"` and `las = 1` don't work on this function. So, I try to find a way using `ggplot2`.

A possible way is to first shape your dataframe and convert y and x axis in an numerical format by attributing the level of their factor format. 
You also need to normalise the "value" column:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF <- as.data.frame(df) %>% mutate(species = rownames(df)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-species, names_to = "X_var", values_to = "values") %>%
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = unique(species))) %>%
  mutate(X_var = factor(X_var, levels = unique(X_var))) %>%
  mutate(NewY = as.numeric(species)*2) %>%
  mutate(normval = values / max(values))  %>%
  mutate(NewX = as.numeric(X_var))  

# A tibble: 15 x 6
   species                    X_var values  NewY normval  NewX
   <fct>                      <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Sphacelaria tribuloides(O) A1         9     2   0.375     1
 2 Sphacelaria tribuloides(O) A2        18     2   0.75      2
 3 Sphacelaria tribuloides(O) A3        20     2   0.833     3
 4 Sphacelaria tribuloides(O) B1         5     2   0.208     4
 5 Sphacelaria tribuloides(O) B2        17     2   0.708     5
 6 Amphiroa rigida (R)        A1         6     4   0.25      1
 7 Amphiroa rigida (R)        A2        18     4   0.75      2
 8 Amphiroa rigida (R)        A3        24     4   1         3
 9 Amphiroa rigida (R)        B1        18     4   0.75      4
10 Amphiroa rigida (R)        B2        18     4   0.75      5
11 Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  A1        16     6   0.667     1
12 Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  A2        18     6   0.75      2
13 Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  A3        16     6   0.667     3
14 Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  B1        19     6   0.792     4
15 Stypocaulon scoparium (O)  B2         8     6   0.333     5
```

Now, you can use `geom_ribbon` to get your kite diagram:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = NewX, fill = species))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = NewY-normval, ymax = NewY+normval))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(DF$NewY), labels = levels(DF$species))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(DF$NewX), labels = levels(DF$X_var), name = "")
```

[image]
Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for!  I would have never thought to normalize the values! Thank you very much, everyone! You've helped me tremendously!

Comment: You're welcome ;). BTW, you should rename your question "Kite Diagram in base R or ggplot2" in order to make it clearer for people searching on the site.