# Kite diagram tidyr

Tags: r, ggplot2, diagram

I was following a previous thread (was uncertain if it was inappropriate to post the question there as it is from 2020) and the code produces a kite graph, however, when using my data the axes are swapped and the value I wanted for the x-axis is also included in the wrong group. I want the x-acis to be quadrat number and the y-axis to be species.

Previous thread: [Kite Diagram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581916/kite-diagram-in-r)

My data looks like this

```r
structure(list(quadrat_number = 0:87, Ulva.sp. = c(12L, 32L, 
24L, 28L, 48L, 16L, 80L, 24L, 80L, 100L, 16L, 32L, 40L, 40L, 
68L, 56L, 28L, 32L, 20L, 8L, 24L, 12L, 0L, 20L, 56L, 32L, 72L, 
48L, 76L, 68L, 20L, 88L, 88L, 0L, 56L, 12L, 12L, 32L, 100L, 28L, 
0L, 0L, 4L, 44L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 0L, 88L, 96L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Hormosira = c(0L, 72L, 24L, 32L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 
8L, 24L, 80L, 4L, 16L, 12L, 16L, 60L, 16L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 
8L, 0L, 64L, 0L, 8L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Bostrychia = c(92L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 0L, 96L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 76L, 0L, 100L, 48L, 
88L, 100L, 28L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 92L, 52L, 
88L, 96L, 20L, 44L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 
0L, 4L, 36L, 4L, 0L, 4L, 84L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 36L, 52L, 20L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Corallina.crustose = c(0L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 8L, 0L, 56L, 0L, 88L, 0L, 
40L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 28L, 64L, 12L, 0L, 76L, 0L, 20L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Jania = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 32L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Pyropia.cinnamomea = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 20L, 52L, 0L, 
4L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 40L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-88L))
```

I followed the code on the other thread.

```
library(plotrix)
kiteChart(dataprune)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dataprune <- as.data.frame(dataprune) %>% mutate(species = rownames(dataprune)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-species, names_to = "X_var", values_to = "values") %>%
  mutate(species = factor(species, levels = unique(species))) %>%
  mutate(X_var = factor(X_var, levels = unique(X_var))) %>%
  mutate(NewY = as.numeric(species)*2) %>%
  mutate(normval = values / max(values))  %>%
  mutate(NewX = as.numeric(X_var))  

ggplot(dataprune, aes(x = NewX, fill = species))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = NewY-normval, ymax = NewY+normval))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(dataprune$NewY), labels = levels(dataprune$species))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(dataprune$NewX), labels = levels(dataprune$X_var), name = "")
```

This produced this graph
[not correct kite diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggwuY.png)
On the other thread they got a graph like this.
[ideal graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXOyp.png)

I think the issue is in the creation of the variables but I'm not sure what to do or how to arrange my data so it'd work in this frame.

If this wasn't clear please tell me. Thanks so much

Comment: Can you review your data sample, please?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly? Should I screen shot my data set? Sorry

Comment: don't screen shot, read the R FAQ for good ways to share data on stack: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info

Comment: Sorry, have ammended. Thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your data is in the wrong shape for `kitePlot()`. You need to make the y-axis variables the row names and the x-axis variables the column names.

Here's an approach with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotrix)
dataprune %>%
   pivot_longer(-quadrat_number, names_to = "organism") %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = quadrat_number, values_from = value) %>%
   column_to_rownames("organism") -> reshaped.dataprune

reshaped.dataprune[,1:5]
#                    0  1  2  3  4
#Ulva.sp.           12 32 24 28 48
#Hormosira           0 72 24 32  0
#Bostrychia         92  0  0 40  0
#Corallina.crustose  0  4  4  4  0
#Jania               0  0  0  0  0
#Pyropia.cinnamomea  0  0  0  0  0

kiteChart(reshaped.dataprune)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time! The code works and I appreciate your explanation