Kite Diagramm in R
i want to do a Kite Diagram in R for my masters thesis.
I used the following code:
setwd("C:/Users/elisa/Documents/Jena/Elisa Wendisch/R_Files/Kite")
data <- read.table(file = "KITE_DipteraS1.txt", header = TRUE, dec = ",", sep = #"\t", na.strings = TRUE)

#clean Dates of X
colnames(data) <- gsub("^X", "", colnames(data))  # Remove leading 'X' added by R
colnames(data) <- trimws(colnames(data))         # Remove leading/trailing spaces

# Reshape the data from wide to long format
data_long <- melt(data, id.vars = "Species", variable.name = "Date", value.name = "Abundance")

unique(data_long$Date)
colnames(data)


# Convert Date column to proper Date format
data_long$Date <- as.Date(data_long$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
data_long$Species <- as.factor(data_long$Species)
# Filter out rows with missing or non-numeric values
data_long <- data_long[!is.na(data_long$Abundance), ]
data_long <- rbind(
  data_long,
  transform(data_long, Abundance = -Abundance)  # Mirror the abundance
)

# Add mirrored abundance for the kite effect

head(data_long)
str(data_long)

ggplot(data_long, aes(x = Date, y = Species, fill = Species, height = Abundance)) +
  geom_area(position = "identity", alpha = 0.7) +  # Use geom_area to create the area plot
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Kite Diagram", x = "Date", y = "Species") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 8)) +  # Rotate and reduce label size
  scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "plasma") +  # Use discrete color scale for species
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "5 days", date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")  # Show every 5th day

And got the following picture:

What is bascically missing is the Kite structure. Is there something in the code preventing it? I would appreciate any help.
I tried to change y into Abundance, which achieves a somewhat kite structure, but i want the Species to be on the y-axis. My goal is to get the species on the y-axis and the kite structur based on the abundance values.

It's quite difficult to say without seeing your actual data in reproducible format (e.g. the output of dput(data), but it seems that you are looking for something more like a horizontal violin plot (i.e. geom_violin instead of geom_area) but we can't give you any concrete advice without seeing your data.

have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60581916/kite-diagram-in-r

Welcome Enix! Thanks for providing your code, but most of it is related to data manipulation and unhelpful to your question, which is about the figure. Could you edit your question to include the output of dput(data_long)? It starts with structure(...)?

Use a geom_ribbon, then facet:
ggplot(data_long) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(
    x = Date,
    ymin = -Abundance/2,
    ymax = Abundance/2,
    fill = Species
  )) +  
  facet_wrap(~Species, ncol = 1, scales = "fixed")

